# Why shouldn't I use IIS Express for ASP.Net Core development?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, iis-express

It seems that .net core needs to be published to run on IIS which means it's either impossible or impractical to debug through IIS, but it's fine with IIS Express. My more experienced colleagues insist that we should do all development with IIS and never IIS Express which is, in effect, saying we should not touch .Net Core.

1) How likely am I to find that the app which works on IIS Express doesn't work on IIS?

2) What's the best way to mitigate the downsides?

3) What should I tell my boss? (I really want to keep working with core)

Comment: 1) using IIS in development makes it easier to deploy. Any way your final deployment environment is IIS. IIS Express is not IIS, so the differences might hurt your deployment of your development is fully on it. 2) .NET Core is also supported on IIS, so I wonder from where you learned that it is not.

Comment: The biggest reason that I can think of to use IIS instead of IIS Express is when you have multiple applications that must interact together. For example, if you have one application that is your Identity Provider, and another application that consumes that Identity Provider, you might want to have your Identity Provider app running on IIS so that it is always running.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason not to debug using IIS Express. You can verify that your deployment works on IIS by publishing to a staging environment or even a local IIS instance.

That being said, it is possible to debug IIS locally by using Attach to Process in Visual Studio if your coworkers simply refuse to use IIS Express.

Answer (score 1):

Its a big difference between iis express and iis(server). on iis server you need to configure first the iis itself. register asp.net, set up .net framework,set up config file and so on.. 
But this would be a good practice for the developer, iis server deployment process. is a must.

Hope it helps your idea..

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer but it is a very important observation.

Answer (score 1):

When working with ASP.NET Core & Visual Studio IDE, its better to use IIS Express (kestrel internally) for following reasons

- Kestrel is a light weight web server built for ASP.NET Core apps. IIS Express will make use of it while development & debugging.
- Hosting IIS for ASP.NET Core apps is for providing load balancing, SSL, gzip etc. So even if you host on IIS, then its fine but development experience will be less productive.
- ASP.NET Core apps are cross platform so you can work on Windows, Linux & MacOS. With IIS your are limiting to Windows only
- Core apps are not like traditional ASP.NET MVC 5 or Web form apps. They have being made easy for development experience.

I would suggest that think of IIS only during deploying Core apps for QA, UAT or PROD. For development need not host on IIS. Hope this helps